# JMeter version 4.0

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I need to know which version of chrome browser is applicable for record scenarios in JMeter version 4.0. My current chrome version is 65.0.3325.181 and I can't record scenarios in JMeter. Please suggest me, whether I can downgrade or upgrade my chrome to achieve this task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: @user7294900  No, but thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your [Chrome Driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) version , download latest 
2.37 version which supporrs Chrome version 66

> Supports Chrome v64-66